# Como enviar mis datos y que al pulsar el mismo botón para enviar me pueda redirigir a mi pagina principal?

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos, formularios

estoy en curso de programación y bueno, como proyecto teniamos que crear una pagina donde se pueda dar altas y bajas de datos, y en la misma pagina web poder editarlo; ah bueno, al intentar guardar los datos modificados, intento que con ese mismo botón me mande a la pagina principal.

Este es mi cabecera:

```
<?php 
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","","",""); 
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Modificar</title>
</head>
<body>
```

El cuerpo del codigo:

```
    <center>
        <h2>Editar Registros </h2>
        <hr /><br>
        <?php 
        include("funciones2.php"); //nombre de tu archivo de funciones
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        select_id('mensajes','id',$id);// donde dice registro va el nombre de tu tabla, y el id
        ?>
        <div>
            <h3>Modifica los parametros que desea cambiar :D</h3>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Nombre:</label></td>
                        <td><input placeholder="Nombre" type="text" value="<?php echo $row->nombre;?>" name="nombre"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Correo:</label></td>
                        <td><input laceholder="Correo" type="email" value="<?php echo $row->correo;?>" name="correo"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Edad:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="number" value="<?php echo $row->edad;?>" name="edad"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Mensaje:</label></td>
                        <td> <textarea  placeholder="Mensaje" cols="40" rows="5" name="mensaje"> <?php echo $row->mensaje;?></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Guardar"></td>
                        <td><a href="mostrardatos.php"><input type="button" value="Regresar" onclick="red()"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Y la parte que para mi es la "mas" esencial, ya que le estoy indicando que cuando se seleccione el *Submit* se puedan enviar los datos. Aquí quise agregar un *Header* pero me salio error.

```
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $field = array("nombre"=>$_POST['nombre'], "correo"=>$_POST['correo'], "edad"=>$_POST['edad'], "mensaje"=>$_POST['mensaje']);
            $tbl = "mensajes"; //nombre de tu tabla de la base de datos
            edit($tbl,$field,'id',$id);
        }
        ?>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo intente también poniendo Onclik en mi submit y tampoco me salio :c
Espero puedan ayudarme :C
Gracias a todos!

Comment: Hola! No pones a qué archivo mandas el formulario. Lo que yo haría sería mandarlo a otra página por ejemplo editar.php y en editar.php poner El código del if(isset($_POST[''submit])) y al final poner el header('index.php');

Comment: Omg! Es cierto @Mundoco !!!
No agregué a donde mandar el formulario!
Gracias! <3

Comment: Estas mezclando código en el cliente, con código en el servidor. Las interacciones de botones, clicks y demás ocurren en cliente. Lo que tienes que hacer es cuando saltes al "edit.php" y hayas completado el UPDATE en la BBDD satisfactoriamente, meterle un header("Location: MiPaginaHome.php");

Comment: corrigiendo mi comentario. Esta mal el header que te puse, es correcto el de @MarcTorres header("Location: index.php");

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
    //aqui iria por ejemplo la instancia que comunica con tu clase
    //la cual tiene la configuracion y el metodo que usar para 
    //hacer alguna accion en tu base de datos etc etc
    $var = new InstanceClass(); 
    $metodo = $var->method($_POST['dato']); 
  } 
?>


//pones el htmlentities para escapar caracteres
<form action="<?php htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?> method="post" >
  <input type="text" name="dato" required>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```